# Integral $\int \frac{\cos(x)+\sin(2x)}{\sin(x)}\text{ d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I would like to evaluate
$$\int \dfrac{\cos(x)+\sin(2x)}{\sin(x)}\text{ d}x\text{.}$$

This is from Stewart's Calculus text, section 7.2., #19. Please note that I don't have a solutions manual and I am not interested in a complete solution.

I would merely like some **guidance on a first step** on approaching this one, since I've gotten 9 similar problems correct, and I hit a brick wall on this one. My first thought was perhaps splitting the fraction like so:
$$\int\cot(x)\text{ d}x + \int\dfrac{\sin(2x)}{\sin(x)}\text{ d}x$$
but this does not look helpful.

Comment: hint : $\sin (2x) = 2\sin( x) \cos (x)$

Comment: A tip for solving integrals that have sin or cosine or some trigonometric function is use a bunch of identities

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Substituting using the double-angle identity
$$\sin (2x) = 2 \sin x \cos x$$
will transform the integrand into an expression that involves only $\sin x$ and $\cos x$, which suggests a particular substitution.

Comment: You don’t even need a substitution: after using the double-angle formula, separate the integrand into two fractions, each easily integrated.

Comment: @Lubin Well, the integral of $\cot x$ is not that easy to remember. I usually recognise the integrand as of the form $\frac{(\sin x)'}{\sin x}$, but that's basically equivalent to substituting $u = \sin x$.

Comment: @Lubin You're quite right, of course, but when a student first encounters this type of integral they may well have only seen integrands involving $\sin$ and $\cos$ and in particular may not yet have seen how to handle $\int \cot x \,dx$.

Comment: @Travis - Thank you for your suggestion. I'm a recent math graduate who's studying for the Math GRE Subject Test, and I want to keep memorization to a minimum, so I appreciate yor answer.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I’m too old. I thought that the integral of tangent was well known, so cotangent (sort of) follows.

Comment: @Lubin I think it *is* well-known to everyone who has learned calculus, but it may not be obvious to people who are only just learning about trig integrals.